# Why do we use manual copy constructors in C++?

Tags: c++

Why do we use manual copy constructors if we have the default? What is the difference between default and manual created copy constructor? Please, give a simple C++ coding example so I would be able to understand easily and quickly. Can we write more than 1 copy constructor?

Comment: You should read up on rule of three, rule of five and rule of zero. Discussing only copy constructors in separation is on one hand too narrow look at it and on other hand there is quite wide variety of reasons why people may need to write copy constructors.

Answer (score 1):

> Why do we use manual copy constructors if we have the default? What is the difference between default and manual created copy constructor?

Default copy constructor does the shallow copy, you define copy constructor when you require to do the deep copy.

for example if you have a pointer in your class and allocating memory dynamically in constructor, In this case you should provide the copy constructors explicitly to do deep copy of pointer content otherwise default copy constructor will copy the pointer itself which most of the time you will not want to do.

> Can we write more than 1 copy constructor?

Copy constructor is having a standard signature so can't be overloaded. There can't be more then once copy constructor.

Comment: "Default copy constructor does the shallow copy, you define copy constructor when you require to do the deep copy" that's super specific to one particular class and wrong in many other cases.

Comment: @Marc pls provide your answer with mentioning such cases. As per my knowledge it will be mostly to do deep copy.

Answer (score 0):

What does it mean to copy an object? its not always obvious how to answer that, so the compiler cannot always know and you have to tell it how to copy.

A simple example:

```
struct Foo {
    int* some_val; // raw pointer only for the sake of the example !!
};
```

The default copy will simply copy members. Is this what you want?

After making a copy of a `Foo` should the copy have `some_val` point to the same instance (shallow copy), or should copying a `Foo` copy the value pointed to by `some_val` as well (deep copy)?

If you use the compiler generated copy you'll get the first. If you want something else you need to supply your own definition of what it means to copy a `Foo`.